# Hosting Multiple WARs in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

After building `APPS.war` with the Tomcat stock `server.xml`, I copied the WAR to `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`.

After I started Tomcat, the WAR exploded, but then, when I navigate to `h_ttp://localhost:8080/APPS/`, I get a `404` error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is shown in the logs?

Comment: Also check you have `welcome-file-list` filled out in the `web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Edit web.xml to include

`<welcome-files>index.jsp</welcome-files>`

where index.jsp is your default page. Otherwise you have to navigate through to the page directly.

`http://localhost:8080/APPS/index.jsp`